# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta de actualización?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lo que necesito es formatear un código que genero y actualizarlo en el registro de cada contacto. Con lo que tengo problemas en formateando el código que debe tener la siguiente estructura.

```
AAA-000-000
```

Las tres primeras letras van siempre, Los últimos 6 dígitos tiene que ser el ID del contacto. y los guiones medios siempre van cada tres caracteres.

```
Tabla CONTACTOS 
id  |  Contacto  | Tipo | Código

Tabla SUGERENCIAS
id | ContactoID | sugerencias
```

En base a las sugerencias necesito generar su código. Como pienso la consulta debería de ser algo así.

```
UPDATE TABLE CONTACTOS
SET 
Barcode = 
(
     SELECT CONCAT('AAA-', RIGHT('00000'), A.id) 
     FROM contactos A 
     INNER JOIN sugerencias B 
     on A.ID = B.contactoID 
     where A.Tipo = 1 and B.Sugerencia = "Pastas"
)
WHERE A = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar una consulta de actualización, que no es más que una consulta habitual dónde agregamos la clausula `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE contactos
       SET Barcode = 'AAA-' + LEFT(RIGHT('000000' + A.id,6),3) + '-' + RIGHT(RIGHT('000000' + A.id,6),3)
       FROM contactos A 
       INNER JOIN sugerencias B
             on A.ID = B.contactoID 
       WHERE A.Tipo = 1 
             AND B.Sugerencia = "Pastas"
```

Comment: Podrías acortar el código usando algo así. `STUFF( RIGHT(1000000 + n, 6), 4, 0, '-')`